# C++ Execution Trace Implementation Suggestions

Tags: implementation, trace, execution

So.  I am completing a project and I'm not sure how to implement a small part of it. I would really appreciate some suggestions :)

The guideline states:

> There is also a role of a systems maintenance person who also has an id to access the system. S/he can turn ON/OFF execution trace. If the trace is ON, then the system will dump the execution traces in a file that can be printed out at a later time by the maintenance person. Each execution trace will log user identification data, time of system access, and the execution trace (which system functions are entered and exited) for the operation conducted by the user.  Thus, the system will dump execution traces, one per customer use of the system, in a sequence bounded by ON/OFF trigger.

I was thinking about using a #DEFINE header, as to make this function globally accessible. But I do not know where to start.  Any tips, or any better ideas/solutions?  And as far as the user data, time and printing the actual file, I have ideas on how to do those.  Just not sure how to implement them.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You really don't want to re-compile all your code every time you turn a feature on or off - this needs to be a run-time thing.

Comment: Yes I agree completely.

Comment: That's the tricky part for me :p

Answer (score 0):

What is usually done is you write a function that writes all your trace into a file however you want to do that (pretty simple). Then before using that function directly you create a boolean flag that denotes weather trace is on or off and you create a macro that uses both of them every time you want a trace. so you would have something like this:

```
bool _isTraceOn;
void writeTraceToFile(char* traceData){...}
#define TRACE(traceData) if (_isTraceOn){writeTraceToFile(traceData)}
```

So when you want to trace you use "TRACE" and that way when you turn on/off trace you just switch the value of _isTraceOn;

Comment: Excellent.  One question though; what do you mean "writes all your trace" ?  Is there a dump that function calls are sent to ? I apologize I have very little experience with C++ and would really appreciate you dumbing things down for me! :) cheers

Comment: No, you have to insert the code above to wherever you want your trace.
I like to have a trace at the entrance of major functions and at specific junctions to see what actually happened in the execution.

Comment: I write the (3rd) #define line into my header, and the (2nd line) void write(...) in my function definitions at the bottom of the source, where does the bool declaration go?

Comment: I'd put it next to the `define`.